# What is meant by the 8 stages of insight?

Tags: theravada, insight, stages-of-the-path

I have heard that there are 8 attainments or stages of insight in the progression of Vipassana, can anyone explain? I'm familiar with the 8 stages of jhana but I believe this is in reference to vipassana specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is 7 purification and [16 stages of insight](http://www.vipassanadhura.com/sixteen.html). See:

- [The Progress of Insight](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/mahasi/progress.html)
- [Transcendental Dependent Arising](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/bodhi/wheel277.html)
- [Relay Chariots](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.024.than.html)
- [7 Stages of Purification & The Insight Knowledges](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/bm7insight.pdf)
- [A Map of the Journey](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/mapjourney6.pdf) (Very readable book)
- [The Development of Insight](http://www.buddhanet.net/imol/develop.htm)
- [The Sixteen Stages of Insight](http://www.vipassanadhura.com/sixteen.html)

NB: Don't get too engrossed in the stages. Many of the naturally manifest them self. You cannot force the development or crave for it to come. Either way you are regressing.